# Flutter: FlexLayoutManager similar to the one in native android

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

So I'm trying to implement a flex listview similar to the google FlexLayoutManager to the horizontal axis with wrap, you can see an example in the wrap section

https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/raw/main/assets/flex-wrap.gif

here is my code:

```
ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: categories.length,
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 16, end: 12),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: (){
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 24,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
                categories[index].name,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```

what I have to add to my listview to make the items wrap and move to the next row if they exceeded the screen width?

Comment: You can use a single Row, and .map or a literal list constructor to map your items into a list of Wrap items.  These will flow based on the provided width of both the Row and the individual items.

Comment: I'd do it as Wrap(children:[for (final c in categories) InkWell(child: Container(child: Text(c.name)))])

Comment: @RandalSchwartz It seems like a good approach, why not post it as a _complete_ answer (with providing more details to the OP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but as I indicated in my comment, I'd use something like:

```
Wrap(
  children: [
    for (final c in categories)
      InkWell(child: Text(c.name)),
    ]);
```

adding of course all your parameters, and the extra container.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use a [`GridView.builder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView/GridView.builder.html) instead of `ListView.builder`:

> Creates a scrollable, 2D array of widgets that are created on demand.

#### result:

I have made my window *very small* and the children still *wrap*:

[image]

With the window *maximized*:

[image]

#### code:

```dart
GridView.builder(
      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
          childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
          crossAxisSpacing: 20,
          mainAxisSpacing: 20),
      itemCount: _categories.length,
      padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 16, end: 12),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          child: Container(
            height: 24,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              categories[index].name,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    )
```